# Redis using too much memory smaller number of keys

Tags: redis

I have a redis standalone server, with around 8000 keys at a given instance .
The used_memeory is showing to be around 8.5 GB.

My individuals key-value size is max around 50kb , by that calculation the used_memory should be less than 1 GB (50kb * 8000)

I am using spring RedisTemplate with default pool configuration to connect to redis

Any idea what should I look into, to narrow down where the memory is being consumed ?

Comment: What is data storage type for your case i.e. are you using normal key-value or hierarchical data type

Comment: I am using zset

Answer (score 0):

`zset` internally uses two data structures to hold the same elements in order to get **O(log(N))** INSERT and REMOVE operations into a sorted data structure. 
The two Data-structures to be specific are,

- Hash Table
- Skip list

Storage for **ideal** cases according to my research is in the following order, 
`hset` < `set` < `zset`

I would recommend you to start using `hset` in case you have hierarchical data storage. This would lower down your memory consumption but might make searching teeny-tiny bit slower (only if one key has more than say a couple of hundred records)